# React Native Integration with Existing Apps and Images

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I'm following the steps described on React native documentation

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "HelloWorld", null);

    setContentView(mReactRootView);
}
```

However, when I try do use the Component Image with images from my android assets, it is not showing.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#images-from-hybrid-app-s-resources

Anyone was integrated a react native app into an Android Application and used images from Assets?

I tried

```
<Image source={{uri:'file:///data/data/com.sampleproject/files/blankProject2/0.1/img/sample.jpeg'}} style={{width: 300, height: 300}}/>
```

and

```
<Image source={{uri: 'img_sample.jpeg'}} />
```

Both situation failed.

Comment: `<Image source={{uri: 'img_sample.jpeg'}} style={{width: 300, height: 300}} />`  try specify width and height ?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android you should do it like this to load images from assets:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'asset:/app_icon.png'}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />
```

with `asset:/` prefixing the image name